# extracting data from pandas multi index dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a multiindex pandas data frame with data as following:

```
dataMyDF.ix[0:3]
                                                   dataMyDF
col1    col2         col3      col4   col5          
W       W            8.0       29.0    4.0       0.291155
P       I            8.0       29.0    7.0       0.108057
N       D            2.0       14.0    16.0      0.247355
```

where col1 through col5 are the index and data is the values. The multi index can be seen as:

```
shape.index[0]
(u'W', u'W', 8.0, 29.0, 4.0)
```

How do I extract data from dataMyDF:

i.e I want to do something like:

```
indexArr = [(W, W, 8.0, 29.0, 4.0), (N, D, 2.0, 14.0, 16.0)]
```

`dataMyDF[indexArr]` to get `[0.291155, 0.247355]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `loc`

```
In [1062]: df.loc[indexArr]
Out[1062]:
                          dataMyDF
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
W    W    8.0  29.0 4.0   0.291155
N    D    2.0  14.0 16.0  0.247355

In [1063]: df.loc[indexArr].values
Out[1063]:
array([[ 0.291155],
       [ 0.247355]])
```

`.ix` inplace of `.loc` works fine too.